# APEX close dialog not refreshing interactive grid on close

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am having trouble refreshing my interactive grid after opening a dialog page to update some data.

There are 3 things that need to run when a user clicks the submit button
-- submit the page and run validation
-- call an oracle proc which will actually run a complex update to multiple tables.
-- close the dialog and refresh the interactive grid.

There is a lot of documentation on doing this and I am following a stackoveflow question "Close modal dialog page and refresh the page Oracle APEX"

But this does not work for me.  If I refresh the page manually after closing the dialog the updates appears.

I think this is because the refresh is running before my proc is finished.  I would like to know how to refresh the whole page after I know the proc has finished and then the dialog will close.

I am opening my dialog using java script instead of the APEX built in: https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/extending-interaction-to-interactive-grids
I am not sure if this is causing an issue.

Thank you for any help you can provide.
code in open the dialog:
     //under the attributes of region where interactive grid is located

```
  function (config)
  {
   var $ = apex.jQuery,
   toolbarData = $.apex.interactiveGrid.copyDefaultToolbar(),
   toolbarGroup = toolbarData.toolbarFind("actions3");

  toolbarGroup.controls.push(
  {
   type: "BUTTON",
   action: "updateCar",
   label: "Edit Selected Cars",
   hot: true,
  });

  config.toolbarData = toolbarData;
  config.initActions = function (actions)
  {
    // Defining the action for activate button
    actions.add(
    {
      name: "updateCar",
      label: "Edit Selected Cars",
      action: updateCar
    });  
 }
  function updateCar(event, focusElement)
{
 var i, records, model, record,
 view = apex.region("ig_car").widget().interactiveGrid("getCurrentView");
 var vid = "";
 model = view.model;
 records = view.getSelectedRecords();
 if (records.length > 0)
 {
    for (i = 0; i < records.length; i++)
    {
      record = records[i];
//    alert("Under Development " + record[1]);
        vid = vid + record[1] + "||";
        apex.item("P18_CAR").setValue(vid);
    }
  }
 }
  return config;
}
```

hidden dialog url:
     `begin
        return sa_car_pkg.prepare_dialog_url( 'f?p=' || v('APP_ID') || ':2:' 
    || V('APP_SESSION') || '::NO:RP:P2_CAR_ID
    :$0$' );
    end;`

sa_car_pkg.prepare_dialog_url:

```
function prepare_dialog_url (
p_url in varchar2 )
return varchar2
is
 begin
   return regexp_substr(
    apex_util.prepare_url( p_url ), 'f\?p=[^'']*');
 end prepare_dialog_url;
```

Thank you for any help !!!

this is also under the attributes of region where interactive grid is located

```
apex.navigation.dialog(url, 
{title:'EditCar',height:'auto',width:'720',maxWidth:'960',
   modal:true,dialog:null},
  "t-Dialog-page--standard", "#btnOpenDialog");
  } else {alert("Please Select at least one car");}
 }
 return config;
```

Comment: Please show the code you are using to open the dialog. Have you created a Dynamic Action on the page you want to refresh (the one opening the dialog) that's listening for the dialog close event to do the refresh? Finally, why do you want to refresh the entire page and not just the IG?

Comment: I have a dynamic action on the dialog close on the page I need refreshed.  The affected Elements are region and the region I where the interactive grid is.  I will add the code I use to open the dialog to the post.

Comment: The code you're showing isn't helping. I still don't see the code where the dialog is opened. I'm looking for some JavaScript code that invokes an API that opens the dialog. Just curious, where is "hidden dialog url" used, in a region? Also, what is `prepare_dialog_url` doing?

Comment: Hi Dan.  I added the code that actually opens the dialog.  Those other fields you mentioned dialog url prepares a dynamic url passing a array of values to the dialog page. I think I need some kind of delay before the page refreshes.  Is there a way I could get a return from the db that the process has finished and then have apex issue the refresh?  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Okay, still trying to figure out a few things here. Are you trying to refresh the IG or the page when the dialog closes?

Comment: I would prefer just the IG but the whole page would be acceptable if that is the only way to get it to work.

Comment: Okay, could you change the title of your question to something like "APEX close dialog not refreshing interactive grid on close"? Regarding the timing, if your dialog page has a PL/SQL process that runs before the Close Dialog process, then it will not close the dialog prior to running the PL/SQL process completing. The only way you'd have a race condition is if the PL/SQL process invoked an async process (scheduled job) to make it seem like the work was done faster. Do you know if that's the case?

Comment: I was able to update the title. Please answer my question about the PL/SQL process.